# Library method does not exist in project but, clearly exists in the code. How do I update my local Golang project to bring in the method?

Tags: go, docker-buildkit

I am working on a Moby Buildkit LLB project in Golang. I have built out almost all of the image builder capabilities.  But, I am having a hard time getting environment variables working.  The current method I am using is to define an llb.ImageConfig with env vars. And use the llb.state.WithImageConfig to add all of the env vars to the state tree. The issue that I currently have is a compilation error.  The code that is throwing the compilation error is :
`s = s.WithImageConfig(imageCfg)` and the error is : `s.WithImageConfig undefined (type llb.State has no field or method WithImageConfig)`

However, I can clearly see that in the llb github repo the method does exist. This is my first go project. So I figured my dependency must be out of date. But, I did a go get to update the dependency and the current version listed in the project `github.com/moby/buildkit v0.11.3` so I think that the dependency should be up to date.

Here is a link to the code that I would like to call : https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/v0.11.3/client/llb/state.go#L232 One thing to note is that I didn't convert the ImageConfig to a byte array. But, I tried that and got the same issues

Comment: I took a look in my vendor folder and noticed that the method doesn't exist on the state as defined in the vendor folder. I am investigating how to remedy taht.

Comment: It's been a while since I used the vendoring feature, but if memory serves `go mod vendor` should update the local copy of the dependency.

Comment: Thank you for the response Peter. I have been having a hard time understanding the difference between the package management systems.  I used Go Mod Vendor. The CLI indicated that it would be updating everything. But nothing changed in the vend folder